# Как заставить gii видеть две базы?

Tags: gii

Изначально необходимые данные лежат в двух разных базах. Для редактирования этих данных нужны два разных модуля. 
даю для одной базы:

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=appstan',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),
```

а что делать со второй?

Comment: это yii фреймворк?

Comment: да, это yii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cкорее всего, у тебя ето не получится, так как максимум что я знаю - это можно для разных моделей прописать в конфиге разные подключения к базам, но чтоб данные 1-ой модели были разбросаны по разным БАЗАМ, то тут только ручками модель собирать и писать все запросы ручками придется.

А почему нельзя все в одну базу закинуть?

Comment: причуды вот такие. пыталась прописать разные подключения в конфиге, но чет не вышло